# How to push a dataframe to Kafka using python and pandas not pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-kafka

I need to push a dataframe to Kafka using python and pandas not pyspark. Is there any material, resources or advice on how i can start off with this

Comment: Spark isn't required to use Kafka with Python. What specific issue are you having using `kafka-python` dependency?

Comment: Kafka works nicely for json schema,avro and protobuf format.
And yes as @OneCricketeer mentioned no need of spark at all.
The idea would be to convert your dataframe to json format and produce the message(publish message to kafka) in json.

Comment: @AkhilJain Kafka doesn't care about the data format. Each entry of the dataframe could be pickled

Comment: @OneCricketeer I agree if you are working exclusively in Python, you could pickle the data you send and receive.But my point is Kafka isn't really suited to send entire matricies/dataframes around.